# ERROR PHP Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002):

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una duda mi código al momento de ejecutar la query me sale el siguiente error :

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002):Se produjo un error durante el
>   intento de conexión ya que la parte conectada no respondió
>   adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en
>   la conexión establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido
>   responder. in C:\xampp\htdocs\smartyard\ymInvoiceOutput.php on line 69
>
> Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\smartyard\ymInvoiceOutput.php on line 69

No se cual es el problema o como aumentar el tamaño máximo de espera de phpmyadmin ya que lo estoy conectando a una database que esta en la nube y no ejecuta

Comment: ¿Una base de datos que está en la nube? ¿Eso qué quiere decir exactamente?

Comment: SI ESTA COLGADA EN PHPMYADMIN POR PARTE DE DREAMHOST

Comment: Eso no es la nube, es un servidor que es una cosa muy distinta. Otra pregunta, ¿el archivo PHP desde el cual intentas conectar está en el mismo servidor (Dreamhost) de la base de datos? ¿Verificaste que para conectar estás usando el código y las credenciales correctas (usuario, contraseña, host...) proporcionados por Dreamhost? Pulsa en [edit] para agregar tu código de conexión, puedes cambiar los datos reales por otros para no revelar tus credenciales de conexión.

Comment: pues creo que la ip de phpmyadmin no la agrege

Comment: esa no se donde encontrarla

Comment: No tienes que poner IP, a no ser que te quieras conectar desde fuera del servidor, lo cual no has dicho ¿? Por favor pulsa en [edit]  y aclara la pregunta, no se entiende nada, ni el contexto ni lo que estás usando para conectarte ni de dónde. Si quieres conectarte desde fuera del servidor tendrás que autorizar conexiones remotas o usar un tunel implementando claves privadas / públicas. Sin conocer el contexto no podemos ayudarte.

Comment: si porque no tengo la base de datos

Comment: No sé exactamente qué quiere decir *no tengo la base de datos*. Si no tienes la base de datos ¿cómo vas a conectarte a algo que no tienes?

Comment: $dblink = mysqli_connect('189.144.165.202', 'FleetAdmin', 'FleetNoOne', 'Yard_Manager') or die( mysqli_error() );
esta es la conexion

Comment: Si el usuario y contraseña son los reales aconsejo que borres tu comentario anterior. Donde pones la IP `189.144.165.202` debes poner `localhost`, porque la base de datos no está en tu IP sino en Dreamhost.

Comment: ya lo cambie
$dblink = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'FleetAdmin', 'FleetNoOne', 'Yard_Manager') or die( mysqli_error() );
y me salio este error

Advertencia : mysqli_connect (): (HY000 / 1045): Acceso denegado para el usuario 'FleetAdmin' @ 'localhost' (usando la contraseña: SÍ) en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ smartyard \ ymInvoiceOutput.php en la línea 69

Comment: Ya vamos mejorando :) Tienes que usar el usuario y contraseña que te dio Dreamhost cuando creaste la base de datos. El error dice claramente *Accesso denegado*, lo cual indica que o el usuario no es correcto, o la contraseña no es correcta o que ambos no son correctos.

Comment: se supone quepara conectar al host

Comment: me dio este waeyaert.teacup.dreamhost.com

Comment: Revisa tu cuenta de Dreamhost, en alguna parte tiene que estar el nombre de usuario y contraseña para la base de datos, si no abre un ticket con el soporte técnico.